# How to mock PermissionAndroid from react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions

I'm building an android app using React-native and using PermissionsAndroid from react-native to get user permission.

```
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native'
```

Now i'm writing unit test and i need to verify the component behaviour based on the Permission.
hence i need to mock PermissionsAndroid.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
jest.mock('react-native//Libraries/PermissionsAndroid/PermissionsAndroid', () => {
  const PermissionsAndroid = jest.requireActual(
    'react-native//Libraries/PermissionsAndroid/PermissionsAndroid',
  );
  console.log(PermissionsAndroid);
  return {
    ...PermissionsAndroid,
    check: jest.fn(() => new Promise(resolve => resolve(true))),
    request: jest.fn(() => new Promise(resolve => resolve(true))),
  };
});
```

Comment: request: jest.fn(() => new Promise(resolve => resolve('granted')))

In this line instead of true I passed 'granted' and it worked for me. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in 2022

```
jest.mock('react- 
 native//Libraries/PermissionsAndroid/PermissionsAndroid', () => {
  return {
   ...jest.requireActual('react- native//Libraries/PermissionsAndroid/PermissionsAndroid'),
   request: jest.fn(() => new Promise(resolve => resolve('granted')))
 }
})
```

Because it is async you have to later on await it e.g. with react testing library `const element = await findByText(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Simply mocking
`jest.doMock('react-native', () => ({  PermissionsAndroid: {...` did not work for me. Here is how I got it to work specifically mocking `requestMultiple` and `check`.

```
let fineLocationPermissionResult: String = PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED;
let courseLocationPermissionResult: String = PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED;

let fineLocationPermissionGranted = true;
let coarseLocationPermissionGranted = true;

const permissionsAndroidModule = jest.requireActual('react-native/Libraries/PermissionsAndroid/PermissionsAndroid.js');
jest.doMock('react-native/Libraries/PermissionsAndroid/PermissionsAndroid', () => ({
  ...permissionsAndroidModule,
  requestMultiple: () => {
    return {
      [PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION]: fineLocationPermissionResult,
      [PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION]: courseLocationPermissionResult,
    };
  },
  check: () => {
    return fineLocationPermissionGranted && coarseLocationPermissionGranted;
  },
}));
```

I've included some of the variables I used in my tests to manipulate the results of the mock but essentially you need to mock the entire module path (`'react-native/Libraries/PermissionsAndroid/PermissionsAndroid'`) and then include the rest of the module that you are not mocking via `jest.requireActual`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution below:

```
jest.mock(
  'react-native//Libraries/PermissionsAndroid/PermissionsAndroid',
  () => ({
    PermissionsAndroid: {
      request: () => {
        true;
      },
      check: () => {
        true;
      },
    },
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with this one and it works perfectly

```js
jest.mock(
  'react-native//Libraries/PermissionsAndroid/PermissionsAndroid',
  () => ({
    request: () => {
      true;
    },
    check: () => {
      true;
    },
  }),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

its better to keep the asynchronous aspect of functions :

```
jest.mock('react-native-permissions', () => {
return {
    requestNotifications: () => new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve({status: 'granted'})
    }),
    request             : () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve('denied')
    }),
    check               : () => new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve('granted')
    }),
    openSettings        : () => jest.fn(),
    PERMISSIONS         : {
        IOS    : {LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE: "ios.permission.LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE"},
        ANDROID: {READ_CONTACTS: "android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"}
    }
}
```

})

Answer (score -1):

You can mock this from react-native directly, just like:

```
    jest.doMock('react-native', () => ({
      PermissionsAndroid: {
        request: (permission: string) => {
          //whatever you want
        },
      },
    }))
```

Notice that you might see some issues with the components you are using for that unit test, i.e. it might show an error if you are using `<View>` from React Native and not mocking it. Given that case, you have to import `<View>` and then include it in your mock.

```
import { View } from 'react-native'
...

    jest.doMock('react-native', () => ({
      View,
      PermissionsAndroid: {
        request: (permission: string) => {
          //whatever you want
        },
      },
    }))
```