# how to mock async PermissionsAndroid.request in jest?

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I have this code in react native i want to make a test:

```
const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
          {
            title: 'Device current location permission',
            message: 'Allow app to get your current location',
            buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
            buttonPositive: 'OK',
          }
        );
```

i am looking at an answer here but seem not working: [How to mock PermissionAndroid from react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62042699/how-to-mock-permissionandroid-from-react-native)

```
jest.doMock('react-native/Libraries/PermissionsAndroid/PermissionsAndroid', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-native/Libraries/PermissionsAndroid/PermissionsAndroid'),
  request: () => ({
    [PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION]: PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED,
  }),
  check: () => true,
}));
```

on ios i am doing it like this which was quick:

```
jest.spyOn(Geolocation, 'requestAuthorization').mockResolvedValue('granted');
```

i can't seem to think of a way how to do it in android?

Answer (score 0):

I could recommend you to try with **react-native-permissions**. It already have a [mock file](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions/blob/master/mock.js) that you can use. You can use Jest + React Testing Library Native.

In my case I used a **jest-setup.js** file

```
import {jest} from '@jest/globals';

jest.mock('react-native-permissions', () =>
  require('react-native-permissions/mock'),
);
```

Then configure jest inside you package.json file

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native-permissions|)"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "./jest-setup.js"
    ]
  }
```

For Geolocation service I created a react-native-geolocation-service inside `__mocks__/react-native-geolocation-service.js`

```
export default {
  getCurrentPosition: jest.fn().mockImplementation(successCallback => {
    const position = {
      coords: {
        latitude: 57.7,
        longitude: 11.93,
      },
    };
    successCallback(position);
  }),
};
```

In your App component you could have this

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import {check, request, PERMISSIONS, RESULTS} from 'react-native-permissions';
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';

const App = () => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);

  const handleLocationPermission = async () => {
    let permissionCheck = '';
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      permissionCheck = await check(PERMISSIONS.IOS.LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE);

      if (permissionCheck === RESULTS.DENIED) {
        const permissionRequest = await request(
          PERMISSIONS.IOS.LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE,
        );
        permissionRequest === RESULTS.GRANTED
          ? console.warn('Location permission granted.')
          : console.warn('Location perrmission denied.');
      }
    }

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      permissionCheck = await check(PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

      if (permissionCheck === RESULTS.DENIED) {
        const permissionRequest = await request(
          PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        );
        permissionRequest === RESULTS.GRANTED
          ? console.warn('Location permission granted.')
          : console.warn('Location perrmission denied.');
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleLocationPermission();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
     Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        position => {
            const {latitude, longitude} = position.coords;
            setLocation({latitude, longitude});
     },
     error => {
       console.log(error.code, error.message);
     },
     {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000},
      );
     }, []);
  
  return (<View></View>)
}
```

Then in you test file you can test the behaviour using React Testing Library Native.

```
import React from 'react';
import {render, waitFor} from '@testing-library/react-native';
import App from '../App';
import {check} from 'react-native-permissions';
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';

describe('<UserScreen />', () => {
  test('should check for permissions', async () => {
    render(<App />);

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(check).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(Geolocation.getCurrentPosition).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

I wrote a similar and more detailed [Post](https://cristianecheverria.com/blog/post28/) on my website.